# Including progress bar in R cluster

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm using *cluster* in the R *raster* library to speed up the processing time when running predictions on sdm models. However, even with all available cores utilised (35), it is taking a long time. Is it possible to incorporate a progress bar so I can view it's progress? When I use *predict* without *cluster*, I can display the progress;

```
pb <- predict(pred_nf, bc, ext=ext, progress='text')
```

However, it does not appear when I include it in the cluster

```
beginCluster()
pb <- clusterR(pred_nf, predict, args=list(bc, ext=ext, progress='text'))
endCluster()
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to put the progress bar code outside of the closed parenthesis.

Try this:

```
   # create a cluster and ID the # of cores to use
    beginCluster(3)

    #predict fxn using clusterR
    r.prob.Cluster<-clusterR(logo, predict, args=list(model.RF),
    progress='text', type='prob')

    endCluster() #delete the cluster
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was able to execute the code using the below alterations. What is the purpose of the r.prob in your code?;                                                                
'beginCluster()'
'pb <- clusterR(predictors, predict, args=list(m),progress='text')'
'endCluster()'

Comment: Glad it worked -please consider accepting my answer (click the check mark) so others will know this is the solution. The r.prob.Cluster is simply the name of the output raster in my code. I was running tests generating the output with and without cluster (if interested see: http://www.timassal.com/?p=1920). The type='prob' is so the output is returned on a probability scale.